# DLL variables conflicting with local variables when Option Explicit Off

Tags: vb6, global-variables, option-explicit

I am maintaining a VB6 program that does not use `Option Explicit`.  I know this is not a good idea but I did not write the code.

An example of my problem is that one variable called `state` has been used in a procedure without `Dim`.

A `DLL` has since been introduced as a reference in the project.  Now the compiler thinks that `state` is referring to a global variable in the `DLL`. Now a line in the code causes a type mismatch error.

How can I avoid this problem?

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241733(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: `Dim` that `state` in the procedure. No other way.

Comment: Ok, but there many other procedures like this - will be very time consuming if that is the only way. The other thing is that even if there is a control on a form with the same name, the DLL variable takes precedence.

Comment: Yep. Or remove the reference to the dll.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too much of a bother, you can make another project as a wrapper around the dll, and only expose what you need. Your VB6 program should reference the wrapper instead of the original dll. If you need the global state from it, you can rename it. If not just hide it.